# Why does this section of code break the whole thing?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am currently trying to recreate Conway's Game of Life for a school project in which we have to make a javascript canvas game, and I have gotten a small grid to appear, but I am having issues with the grid itself in terms of arrays.

```
var cellCount=20;
var currentGrid[cellCount][cellCount];
var nextGrid[cellCount][cellCount];

for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<20;j++){
        currentGrid[i][j]=0;
        nextGrid[i][j]=0;
    }
}

var canvas=document.getElementById('grid');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');



function drawGrid(h,w,id){
    for(var x=0;x<w;x++){
        ctx.moveTo(0,x*20);
        ctx.lineTo(h,x*20);
        ctx.lineWidth=1;
        ctx.strokeStyle='rgb(211,211,211)';
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    for(var y=0;y<h;y++){
        ctx.moveTo(y*20,0);
        ctx.lineTo(y*20,w);
        ctx.lineWidth=1;
        ctx.strokeStyle='rgb(211,211,211)';
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

drawGrid(421,421,'grid');
```

I know there isn't much here but the part that is preventing the grid from appearing is the first three lines. Thanks.

Comment: The second and third lines are syntax errors. `var` is only used to declare a variable. What are those lines supposed to do?

Comment: Problem is here

var currentGrid[cellCount][cellCount];
var nextGrid[cellCount][cellCount];

You haven't declare the vars.. it should be something like this..

var currentGrid = [cellCount,cellCount];
var nextGrid = [cellCount,cellCount];

Comment: keep your browser debug console open!

Comment: @Harsheet - Not in JS. `var currentGrid = [cellCount,cellCount];` creates an array with two elements that both have the value `cellCount`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var currentGrid[cellCount][cellCount];
var nextGrid[cellCount][cellCount];
```

do:

```
 var currentGrid = new Array(cellCount).fill().map(() => new Array(cellCount).fill(0));
 var nextGrid = new Array(cellCount).fill().map(() => new Array(cellCount).fill(0));
```

Comment: I think it's C syntax, not Java. Either way, this fills every element of the outer array with references to a single inner array.

Comment: you'll want `var currentGrid = new Array(cellCount).fill().map(() => new Array(cellCount).fill(0));`

Comment: I dont get your point @Jaromanda If you're taking the es6 approach maybe you should use let instead of var?

Comment: The point is that your way, `currentGrid[0]`, `currentGrid[1]`, `currentGrid[etc]` all refer to the *same* array. So if you change `currentGrid[0][0]` you'd then find that `currentGrid[1][0]` shows the new value too.

Comment: @mika - I only used `=>` to shorten the code for a comment - the point was what @4castle and @nnnnnn pointed out

Comment: This worked really well, thanks! I hate to be a bother but how would you recommend going about making the grid clickable? I'm trying to recreate Conway's Game of Life for a school project due in a couple of days and I'm very lost. Thanks.